# Whats is the best way to interact with the server of a JWS java application

Tags: java, netbeans, java-web-start, japplet

Im having some trouble determining how to write files using a Java Web Start program, I want to write files to the server describing files that have been uploaded to a cloud server. I also want to be sent data such as file names and paths from the client so that I can create a connection between the user and the cloud storage facility and send their files to it.

Currently when i try to run my Web Start Application it works fine and gives no errors, but simply will not write Files and Folders to the Server it resides on. For example, the following code does not work:

```
new File ("ArFile Clients\\File Data\\" 
        + user.getCompany().getName() + "\\" + user.getUsername()).mkdirs();
```

This directory is located on the server and it created to store data on users of the app. But during runtime it is simply ignored or not executed.

I am not using sockets or FTP or anything like that, the cloud server has its own custom library which I am using, I know for a fact that the issue must lie with how Java Web Start works, I just cant find any good examples involving creating files on the server machine and extracting data from a clients machine (just filesystem data like directories and files)

Comment: A JWS application *runs locally* even if it was *downloaded remotely*; JWS is a client-side technology. Also, "Simply ignored or not executed" is likely a wrong conclusion. This is not the nature of the beast.

Comment: Perhaps re-write the title to ask the real question: "How can JWS access/modify 'Cloud' files?" (Or what similarly *captures the intent*.)

Comment: well i cant tell what is happening behind the scenes, but no files are written to the server machine, so will i need to use URL's or something to get this working? Also would using an Applet instead be a better option for what i want to do?

Comment: A JWS application **runs locally** even if it was *downloaded remotely* .. ("Locally" is only "the server" if you are **running it on** -- which is different from *downloading it from* -- "the server" machine.)

Comment: yeh I gathered that, but what im asking now is what would be the best solution to use the applet based on my goals

Comment: **Applets and JWS run the same way**. (As of late, Applets even *use* the JWS container/launcher, albeit in a masked form.)

Comment: so im going to have to use TCP sockets or something like that then?

Comment: See my suggestion for where to direct the question. But no. Using TCP sockets is too difficult (it is far too low-level).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think some explanations of what webstart really is will be relevant here :)

First of all, web start is something that runs on the client JVM.
Yes, it uses jnlp file where you should specify urls of the dependent jars/other resources.
All that web start does is reads this jnlp file (again on client side), parses, figures out the list of urls where the resources exist and donwloads them onto the client machine.
Physically this is achieved by using javaws utility that one can find in

%JDK_HOME%\bin 
folder.
Just like ''java'' gets as an input a series of class-files/jars and spawns a jvm, javaws gets a jnlp, reads it, brings resources and spawns a jvm :)
There is some additional stuff, the web start can do (like auto updates) but this is a 'core functionality'.

Bottom line, if you do want to write some files on server, web start is a wrong way to go.

Conceptually once your application gets loaded and you want to store files on server - create some kind of connection to the server machine from client and upload your files there. One way or another it can't be done with Web Start :)

I hope it helps

Comment: ok well based on this information, i think ill stick with JWS but just forget the server machine entirely, its not what I desired, but at the end of the day the program can function properly without server interaction. Still though, im trying to run the .jnlp file on the server machine (which makes it also the client as well right?) and this is still not writing files, however if i go into netbeans and run the file itself it works perfectly :S

Comment: Hi, as I said web start doesn't write files by itself. If just downloads the urls (usually its jars or resources like pictures, sound files, etc) internally. in order to run the web start manually you can use 'javaws your-jnlp-file.jnlp' - this will work. You can write/read teh files from within your application if this doesn't work there should be an exception that specifies what exactly fails...

Comment: yeh i am running the jnlp file, its just not writing, and as far as i can tell no exceptions have been thrown, im trying a few things to see if they are the problem, ill get back shortly on if it still remains an issue ( and when i say writing, this is writing files within the code using a buffered writer )

Comment: *"Conceptually once your application gets loaded and you want to store files on server - create some kind of connection to the server machine from client and upload your files there. One way or another it can't be done with Web Start :)"*  Since a JWS app. can communicate with a web service based at the home server while sand-boxed, and a foreign server if trusted, that last sentence makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Well at any rate I've simply decided to store everything on the client machine now. Anyways my app is still not working as its meant to even with it now being designed to be totally client-side. I think its to do with a conversion file conversion library however, so that's a question for a different place, thanks for the clarification of JWS, I'm still a little lost on it but I have more direction now at least